# Presenting and hiding popovers on iPads with animation

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, uipopover

I am looking for a way to present and hide a popover in my application using fade in/out animations. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you saying you want to do a custom animation rather than the default popover animation?

Answer (score 0):

```
PopOverDesignController *objPopOverDesignController = [[PopOverDesignController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PopOverDesignController" bundle:nil];
    UIPopoverController *popController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:objPopOverDesignController];
    popController.delegate = self;
    popController.popoverContentSize = objCategoriesViewController.view.frame.size;

    [popController  presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(130,970,100,100)
                                         inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];



[popController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fadein/fadeout your popover, you need to set the modal transition style to CrossDissolve in your controller with **[modalTransitionStyle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/modalTransitionStyle)** property

**Swift**

```
vc.modalTransitionStyle =  UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
```

**Objective c**

```
vc.modalTransitionStyle.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
```

Where **vc** is the view controller that you want to present